# AltBeacon Ranging Examples never returns a result

Tags: android, ibeacon, altbeacon, region-ranging

I'm currently working on a android app that detects nearby beacons, i'm using the AltBeacon API, i tried a modified version of the Ranging Example code given [here](https://altbeacon.github.io/android-beacon-library/samples.html).

Here is my code

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements BeaconConsumer {

    protected static final String TAG = "RangingActivity";
    private BeaconManager beaconManager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        BeaconManager.setsManifestCheckingDisabled(true);

        beaconManager = BeaconManager.getInstanceForApplication(this);

        beaconManager.getBeaconParsers().add(new BeaconParser().
                setBeaconLayout("m:3-4=0215,i:4-19,i:20-21,i:22-23,p:24-24"));

        beaconManager.bind(this);
    }
    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        beaconManager.unbind(this);
    }
    @Override
    public void onBeaconServiceConnect() {
        beaconManager.setRangeNotifier(new RangeNotifier() {
            @Override
            public void didRangeBeaconsInRegion(Collection<Beacon> beacons, Region region) {
                if (beacons.size() > 0) {
                    Log.i(TAG, "The first beacon I see is about "+beacons.iterator().next().getDistance()+" meters away.");
                }
            }
        });

        try {
            beaconManager.startRangingBeaconsInRegion(new Region("myRangingUniqueId", null, null, null));
        } catch (RemoteException e) {    }
    }
}
```

i added this line

```
BeaconManager.setsManifestCheckingDisabled(true);
```

because otherwise the application crashes at the start. [ref](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30499138/servicenotdeclaredexception-the-beaconservice-is-not-properly-declared-in-andro)

and i added a beaconParser to parse my beacons (iBeacon layout)

```
beaconManager.getBeaconParsers().add(new BeaconParser().
                setBeaconLayout("m:3-4=0215,i:4-19,i:20-21,i:22-23,p:24-24"));
```

The probleme is that i can't get any response in the logcat terminal, it's like if it can't detect my beacons.

I am using a motorola Moto G (3rd Gen) with Android 6.0, and i have given the necessary permissions

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN"/>
```

any ideas what could cause the issue ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot detect beacons so long as you are having the crash "fixed" by putting in the line `BeaconManager.setsManifestCheckingDisabled(true);`  That line is a workaround for automated test situations where actual beacon detections are not needed.  So you must remove this line and solve the crash a different way.

If using Eclipse, you need to enable manifest merging (see the same ref you point to above) to get this to work.  If using Android Studio or another IDE, it may be an issue of how you are referencing the library.  If this is the case, please show how you link it with your project.

Comment: I am using Android Studio, i've extracted the .jar file from the AltBeacon-library-2.8.1.aar and added it manualy this gave me `compile files('libs/android_beacon_lib.jar')` in the App>build.gradle file.
i've deleted the library and tried putting `compile 'org.altbeacon:android-beacon-library:2+'` under dependencies in the same file i am now getting a response in the info logcat, but the problem now is that i can't see any objects in my app ( buttons, textviews... ) and it doesnt detect nearby beacons, even though i can detect them using the same layout using Locate app

Comment: What line do you now see in LogCat if you do not detect beacons?

Comment: here is the result in LogCat:

`05-26 13:23:04.437  20616-20987/com.aiboud.ucef.mybeaconparseur I/RangingActivity﹕ didRangeBeaconsInRegion, number of beacons detected = 0`